# How to not attach SQL statement to connection in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

When I save a SQL statement in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, the statement is bound to a specific connection, regardless of whatever connections are being shown at the time in the GUI.

Is this a bug or is there a method to work around this default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click inside the query (in SSMS), choose Connection | Change Connection.

Comment: That is helpful. Hoping there is a preference that when the database is disconnected in the GUI (left-hand side) that all queries attached to the database are disconnected.

Comment: @Paul - No - sorry. The left-hand side (in a default install) is the object browser, it operates independently from your queries, and vice-versa.